# combine diff side-by-side with suppress-common-lines and context options

Tags: unix, diff

How can we get an output similar to what we expect from `diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines --context=3`?

---

One can use `diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines file1 file2` to have side-by-side reduced view for a patch.

Or use `diff --context=3 file1 file2` or `diff --unified=3 file1 file2` to have a the context displayed around the changes.

But upon combining `--side-by-side` and `--context` or `--unified` we get the error:

> diff: conflicting output style options

Comment: Give `vimdiff` a try. You'll like it.

Comment: TBH, by that time, I was really avoiding vim. A year and half now, and I'm almost always using it ':D

Comment: Also try `gvimdiff`.  The GUI version of `vimdiff`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The problem with vimdiff is that it crashes for very large files. We need it to discard *most* of the common lines at the diffing algorithm (keeping some for context) and then have vim only show what remains. At the moment this isnt how it works (vim keeps it all in the buffer in case you want to expand the common lines)